# External DNS + Ingress Nginx + AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress, external-dns

I got the following setup:

Ingress-Nginx-Controller (serviceType "NodePort")

AWS-Load-Balancer-Controller

External-DNS

I am exposing the Ingress-Nginx-Controller via an Ingress, backed by the AWS Load Balancer Controller both public and private. I chose this route, since it was pretty easy to limit the inbound CIDRs. And nginx ingress cannot create an ALB but only Classic LB or NLB.

kubectl -n ingress-nginx get ing

```
NAME CLASS  HOSTS  ADDRESS  PORTS  AGE
alb-ingress-connect-nginx  alb  *  xxxx.region.elb.amazonaws.com  80 2d8h
```

This ingress forwards all traffic to my nginx controller.

The service looks like

```
kubectl -n ingress-nginx get svc
NAME  TYPE CLUSTER-IP  EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S) AGE
ingress-nginx-controller  NodePort a.b.c.d
```

I am trying to automatically setup dns records for my deployment via External-DNS. Therefore, I am creating an ingress for my deployment with ingress-class `nginx` and specified hostname.

Creating the records works, however it uses the IP of my ingress-nginx-controller service (a.b.c.d) instead of the loadbalancer's address.

Now my question: Is it possible to for external-dns to lookup the address of the nginx ingress or does this work only if the Nginx is exposed as service of type "LoadBalancer"?

Thanks for any help

Comment: you can directly use AWS ALB, tho without ingress nginx + External DNS without ingress nginx,

under the hod ingress nginx using AWS CLB ,

seem like its overlapping each other.

Comment: I don’t want to create an alb for each ingress as it adds up the cost.

Comment: then don't use alb, just use nginx and add annotations to nginx service to create loadbalancer

Comment: and ALB Ingress controller support Multiple domain and path when just using 1 ALB, you need to annotate the ingress with same group, even when you have multiple ingress manifest

Comment: then don't use alb, just use nginx and add annotations to nginx service to create loadbalancer - that can only create a classic LB or an NLB. I want an ALB for security purpose so I can use WAF with it

Comment: and ALB Ingress controller support Multiple domain and path when just using 1 ALB, you need to annotate the ingress with same group, even when you have multiple ingress manifest - do you mean we can have just 1 ALB and we can manage routes and paths with it? If yes, could you please share how?

Comment: https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/ingress/annotations/#group.name
https://blog.sivamuthukumar.com/aws-load-balancer-controller-on-eks-cluster

Answer (score 0):

I am able to figure this out by using `--publish-status-address` in nginx controller to point to ALB.
If you are using 2 ALBs (public and private), you need to create 2 nginx controllers with `--publish-status-address` points to each ALB. Also, remember to disable `--publish-service` parameter. And use different `electionID` for each controller if you have installed nginx controllers using Helm